# How to create user that have permission just system batch in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

I need a create user account that have permission just systems batch in Active Directory?  Specifically restrict user to execute batch files only in directory.

Comment: You mean that restrict user to execute batch files only in directory ?

Comment: Yes friends I need that.

Comment: You need to make new user and grant specific permissions only. These answers will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2928738/14919621